# store images as array or enum: which is better?

Tags: java, android

I'm in the process of building my first application for android and also my firsts application in Java. I can't seem to grasp the difference between an enum and an array list. I am building a simple flash card application that will have flash cards with questions on them stored as image files and answers. I want to be able to display the flashcards at random and in progressive order of difficulty. What is the advantage to storing my flash cards in an enum versus an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enum and ArrayList are so far apart in definition, that you should probably read up on enums to fully clarify.

An enum is a pre-determined list of values that describes one thing.  I use enums for things like status, short list of possible values, etc.  For example

```
enum Status {
    Initialized,
    InProgress,
    Completed,
    Failed
};
```

These all define a possible value for something's status.

For something like a Flashcard app, I'd say you could use a combination of both.  You probably need a class that represents the flashcard, and separate your idea of the Flashcard from the image of a Flashcard.  The image is actually just one property of the Flashcard.

Here's an example using both:

```
public class Flashcard {

    public enum Difficulty
    {
        Easiest,
        Easy,
        MediumEasy,
        Medium,
        MediumDifficult,
        Difficult,
        MostDifficult
    }

    String question;
    String answer;
    String pathToImageFile;

    Difficulty difficulty;

}
```

So, this class would represent your Flashcard as an object.  And your app could have some way of creating an ArrayList of this class (`ArrayList<Flashcard>`) and providing an instance of this for a particular difficulty level to your Activities.

What I would actually do is use and Integer for difficulty level so I could have a wider range of difficulty levels having to maintain and update a huge list of enum values as well as having a clearer concept between more and less difficult, but I wanted to show you a common use of enums as an example.

Here's the wikipedia link for enum:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type

Comment: Maybe the flashcard topic (geography, music, politics etc.) would be a better candidate for the enum?

Comment: Thanks! I feel like I understand the usage of an enum so much better now! I probably will use both!

Answer (score 2):

I'd store any image information in an array. Those can be dynamically populated, while enums can't.

Arrays also provide a series of manipulation methods which might come in handy later on.

If you create a HashMap you can also having the level of difficulty to be the key of the map will make it easier for you to display cards in a progressive order, using a structure like:

HashMap < Integer difficultyLvl, ArrayList < Cards > cardsOnSameDifficultyLvl >

Using ArrayList and HashMap will make the application easier add/delete/edit cards at runtime and the structures can be populated from a text file, or even from the directory/filename structure.
Using Enums will hardcode every card in the business logic of the application, making it hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using a HashMap! I will have to read up on that!